# PHP Files showing blank white screen. Cannot fix regardless of trying many fixes

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am trying to install PHP and learn it on my Arch Linux system. However, after installing all the modules and configuring all the files, I am running into an issue.

My HTML files are showing completely fine and I don't think I am currently running into any issues with them. However, my PHP files turn out blank and I am simply greeted with a dreadful fully blank white screen when trying to access my output. I have tried many fixes from reinstalling all my packages related to this and changing around configuration files but I can't find any sign of life.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Here's the guide I used:
https://www.tutofox.com/linux/manjaro-install-apache-mariadb-mysql-php-lamp/

Comment: Did you install Apache as well or any other Web Server? PHP only runs on the web server

Comment: Have you enabled error messages in PHP? Test adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the code in your PHP file.

Comment: Have a look at the HTML source code in your browser. My guess is that you will see your PHP there, meaning that the PHP is not interpreted by your server. Also note that the default extension, of HTML files with PHP in them, is not `.html` but `.php`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Shouldn't it display as text then, directly in the browser?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo No, the browser with see it as the beginning tag of a HTML element, given it starts with `<` and ends with `>`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. The browser "helpfully" converted it to an HTML comment o_0..

Comment: @RiggsFolly not sure. what are some examples?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i think you're correct! what's a fix for this?

Comment: @Axqua what is the file name?

Comment: @Exampleperson index.php

Comment: My best guess is, and this is the easiest one to solve, that you load the HTML or PHP files, on your Arch Linux system, directly into your browser. That way you bypass the web server and since it is the web server which will hand off the PHP to the interpreter, you see the raw PHP code. You have to use an URL like: `http://localhost/my_page.php`.

Comment: Try taking a look at the guide again. There doesn't seem to be an issue with the guide. It seems like you might have missed a step.

Also, you might be actually opening the .php file from the file-manager directly.

Since you said in the comments that the file's extension is .php, there shouldn't be an issue with `AddHandler` either.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I used localhost/index.php

Comment: @Exampleperson I just finished the guide again and I have not missed any step. Seems like my files are being loaded as html regardless of the php extension.